# Can I tap a creature in response to it being tapped?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My buddy uses [Dromoka Dunecaster](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dromoka%20Dunecaster) to tap my [Humble Defector](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Humble%20Defector).  Can I in response activate Humble Defector's ability?

Answer (score 4):

You can't respond to "being tapped"; you can only respond to spells being cast and abilities being activated or triggered.

And that's what you have here. Your opponent activated Dromoka Dunecaster's ability, after which you both get a chance to cast instants and activate abilities in response (i.e. before it resolves).

You are free to activate Humble Defector's ability at this time<sup>[1]</sup><sup>[2]</sup>. Having been placed on the stack last, it will resolve first. When it resolves, it will have you draw two cards and then give your opponent control of Humble Defector.

When Dromoka Dunecaster's ability then resolves, it does nothing<sup>[CR 609.3]</sup> since a permanent that's tapped can't be tapped<sup>[CR 701.17a]</sup>.

---

1. If it's your turn, due to the limitation imposed by the ability.
2. Technically, your opponent gets first dibs since it's their ability to which you are responding<sup>[CR 601.2h]</sup>. That said, in a tournament setting, it's assumed that a player passes when they get priority in response to casting an spell or placing an ability on the stack unless they explicitly retain priority.

---

> 601.2h Once the steps described in 601.2a–g are completed, the spell becomes cast. Any abilities that trigger when a spell is cast or put onto the stack trigger at this time. If the spell’s controller had priority before casting it, he or she gets priority.
>
> 609.3. If an effect attempts to do something impossible, it does only as much as possible.
>
> 701.17a [...] Only untapped permanents can be tapped

Comment: Slightly incorrect. A spell that says "tap target permanent" can target and "tap" a tapped permanent. It's why spells that say "tap target permanent. it doesn't untap during its controller's next untap step" work on a tapped creature.

Comment: @JonTheMon, No, it can't. *701.17a [...] Only untapped permanents can be tapped.* For example, an ability that reads "Tap or untap target permanent" forces you to toggle it. (That's why the text of [Elder Druid](http://magiccards.info/7e/en/238.html) and many others was changed to "*You may* tap or untap target permanent".) If you could tap a tapped permanent, "{T}: Add one {G} to your mana pool" would give you infinite mana. In the OP's case, the effect skips the tapping, doing as much else as it can [CR 609.3].

Comment: Hmm, so the targeting is separate from the actual action performed (or not performed or skipped)?

Comment: @JonTheMon, Completely separate. 1) Targets are chosen when the spell is cast, ability is activated or triggered ability is placed on the stack. The effect is performed when the spell resolves, which only happens after all players get a chance to cast more spells and such. 2) You only look at the targeting condition when choosing targets. For example, the only relevant part of "Tap target flying creature. Draw two cards." when choosing targets is "flying creature". Whether the effect is likely to eventually succeed (e.g. if it's currently tapped or not) is of no consequence.

Comment: @JonTheMon, 3) A spell/ability that targets and only has illegal targets is countered as it would resolve (so none of the effect occurs). Other spells/abilities resolve, doing as much as possible. For example, if the creature targeted by "Tap target flying creature. Draw two cards." loses flying, the spell/ability is countered and you don't get to draw any cards. If instead it's tapped when the spell/ability resolves, then you don't tap the creature, but you still get to draw two cards.

Comment: @JonTheMon: if it said "tap target untapped permanent", then it couldn't target a tapped permanent. But the way you phrase it, it can _target_ any permanent.

Comment: @JonTheMon with abilities like this there is always confusion, but ikegami explains it perfectly.

Comment: @ikegami can you add what you said in the comments to your answer, it would give a more clear picture :)

Comment: @Wouter, I'm not sure a discussion about the effects of invalid targets has anything to do with the question. There sure are lots of questions about that, but this isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if it is your turn, Humble Defector’s ability can be activated any time, including in response to a spell or ability. Dromoka Dunecaster's ability is put on stack, you have the opportunity to respond and use Humble Defector’s ability, tapping it to pay the cost.